# Incorrect Order State

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders, order-state

In magento1, In some of my orders, the state seems to be corrupted (or I am thinking this way). There are some pending orders which are not getting cancelled or confirmed. They are in pending state only. Attaching a sample screenshot. Can someone give some pointers how to fix this?
[image]

Comment: That happens only for specific payment method?

Comment: @kunj no. its for any method.

Comment: check what state assign to Pending Payment status?

Comment: Ok, Maybe anyone module doing this or check in admin > system > Order Statuses.